# bash - In a csv file, get the last column of all duplicate and concatenate to first occurence

Tags: bash, csv

I have a sorted csv file, where several entries are duplicates, except for the last column. How can I concatenate all the last columns to the first occurrence of each entry ?

Input:

> Test1,123,somestuff
>
> Test1,123,differentstuff
>
> Test2,345,otherstuff

Output:

> Test1,123,somestuff, differentstuff
>
> Test2,345,otherstuff

**EDIT:**
Obtaining the last column is easy (`cut -d, -f3 test.csv`); now I need to add it to every first occurence of an entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ***awk*** utility:

```
awk -F, '{ k=$1 FS $2; a[k] = (k in a)? a[k] FS $3 : $3 }
         END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' OFS=',' csvfile
```

The output:

```
Test1,123,somestuff,differentstuff
Test2,345,otherstuff
```

---

- `-F,` - field separator
- `k=$1 FS $2` - associative array key (grouping records by the first 2 field values)

Comment: Thanks, however it seems that there is a colon that is added on the last column. Any idea how to remove it ? Otherwise this seems to work fine.

Comment: `Test2,345,,otherstuff` and `Test1,123,,somestuff,differentstuff` are what your script return me

Comment: @user96649, that should not happen. I have used the input from your question and the result is fine. Otherwise you have posted nonactual, improper input

Comment: It's strange, but it wasn't hard to remove the comma (not a colon). Thanks you for your help